# Probability mass function sum 2 dice roll?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dice, tensorflow-probability

Triying to plot pmf for 2 dice sum, but some tail-right problems occur.

I have tried using numpy and other python libraries and the problems stays:

```python
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a=500000
dado1_=evaluate(tf.cast(tfp.distributions.Uniform(low=1,high=7).sample(a),tf.int32))
dado2_=evaluate(tf.cast(tfp.distributions.Uniform(low=1,high=7).sample(a),tf.int32))

plt.hist(np.add(dado1_,dado2_))
```

```
expecting symetric distribution centered at 7 with gaussian form,
assymetric found
```

[outputplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzZ7X.png)

Comment: Works fine using just numpy. By the way you are wrong about the expected shape - it is triangular centered at 7. It will be gaussian if you sum a few more of these uniformly sampled variables.

Comment: Yes. thats true. When i said gaussian i was meaning triangular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the graph, it seems like the area between the tick mark for 2 and 3 is the number of rolls that sum to 2. 3-4 is 3, and so on.

Is it possible that between tick marks 11 and 12 contains the number of rolls that sum to 11 *and* 12? It could explain why the graph seems shorter on the right side than it should be, as well as why the last bar is taller than expected.

Comment: Thanks very much. It was just that. Changing bins in hist function solves the problem:      plt.hist(np.add(dado1_,dado2_),bins=len(np.unique(np.add(dado1_,dado2_))))                                                                    Ithougth that matplotlib was doing this for us

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow_probabilty.Uniform is a continuous distribution, not discrete. So it’s not really going to model dice rolls appropriately.

Comment: that wasnt the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the dice rolls, you'd want `tfd.Categorical`:

```py
import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
tf.enable_v2_behavior()
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions
tfb = tfp.bijectors

# 10 independent 1-die samples
print(tfb.AffineScalar(shift=1.)(tfd.Categorical(logits=tf.zeros([6]), dtype=tf.float32)).sample(10))

# 10 independent pairs-of-dice samples
d = tfb.AffineScalar(shift=1.)(tfd.Categorical(logits=tf.zeros([6]), dtype=tf.float32))
print(tfd.Sample(d, 2).sample(10))
```

Comment: this may work, but it was matplotlib problem  not tf. Thanks a lot